# Как вывести всю информацию из ManagementObjectSearcher?

Tags: c#, winforms

Например у меня есть такая часть кода:

```
foreach (var mo in new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\cimv2", "select * from Binary").Get())
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add((string)mo["Caption"])
            }
```

Я могу обратиться конкретно к `Caption`, `Data` или другим полям, через `mo[""]` или `mo.GetPropertyValue("");`, чтобы получить их значение.

Но что делать, если я хочу получить все значения из этого списка, например тут: `Caption`, `Data`, `Description`, `Name` (и т.д.). Я конечно  могу, как выше, обращаться к каждому полю, но если я хочу, например, поменять Win32_Binary на Win32_Battary.

В таком случае придётся менять и все обращения к полям. Думаю, что должен быть способ сделать это проще, но не могу нигде найти. Если кто знает, буду рад помощи. Спасибо.

Comment: `mo.Properties`, в нем все свойства объекта, выводите его циклом, или как хотите еще. Само свойство это `PropertyData` объект, который содержит `Name` и `Value`.

Comment: Спасибо! Именно то что я искал